# Store data in AWS SimpleDB with a html form, is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm noob with AWS and I need help to store data in simpleDB, I really dont know how to begin. Is there a way (tutorial, examples) to do this?
I've been searching on amazon docs but I don't understand anything. I need help please.
What I need is a html form to send data to simpleDB (insert, delete, update).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

`Amazon SimpleDB` can be useful for those who need a non-relational database for storage of smaller, non-structural data. `Amazon SimpleDB` has restricted storage size to 10GB per domain and it can achieve up to 25 writes/second. `Amazon SimpleD` offers simplicity and flexibility. SimpleDB automatically indexes all data. Amazon SimpleDB pricing is based on your actual box usage. You can store any UTF-8 string data in Amazon SimpleDB.

For more detail-

`Amazon SimpleDB` [documentation](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/simpledb/).